# __init__.py only import defined functions

Tags: python, package

I have a package that uses a `__init__.py`:

```py
from .common import (funcA, funcB, funcC)
from .other import (funcD, funcE, funcF)
```

I am literally having to import every single function manually because if I try to do `import *` it drags all the modules used in `common.py` and `other.py` with it. i.e. things like `os`, `re`, `sys`, etc. will get dragged into the package's namespace.

Is there a way to import all the functions that are actually defined in the file, rather than importing the entire namespace from the module?

Comment: Are you looking for [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) ([also](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package); in `common` and `other`)? At least it sounds like it.

Comment: So I'd be looking for a way to automatically fill `__all__` with the functions defined in the module file.